# Parse.com: How do I create a clone of one App

Tags: parse-platform

We are collaborators on a Parse.com App and we need to recreate the App in another account as we are ending our relationship with the original App creators.

We have copied all the classes and exported all the data from the previous App but are getting errors with the JavaSript API (Access Denied/403 issue).  Has anyone else experienced this?  What did you do to overcome the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Parse.com dashboard has export to JSON which you can then import from the data browser on your second app.

Object IDs will not be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

One big thing to be aware of:
Any referenced PFFiles are NOT exported, so all the references in your rows are not valid, as the new database is not part of the ACL of the old PFFiles.

Either export+import the PFFiles manually, or change the ACLs, if that is indeed possible.